# Dijkstra algorithm: Are all shortest paths acyclic?

Tags: shortest-path, dijkstra

I know that the algorithm wont terminate if it reaches negativ cycles and
a path wouldnt be a shortest path, if it would contain a cycle with distance greater than 0.

My question is what happens if there exists a shortest path with a cycle of distance 0 , would the algorithm include that cycle into the shortest path?

Would you say all shortest paths are acyclic?

Comment: Are you referring to a weighted graph?

Comment: yes , as example my theoretical cycle of distance 0 could be a cycle with weights 1 ,1 and -2  which would result into a cycle distance of 0.

Answer (score 0):

With the Dijkstra algorithm, All paths are guaranteed to be acyclic as long as there are no negative paths. Dijkstra adds a path to a node as soon as a path is found, and only updates that path if a new, cheaper path is found. Since 0 < 0 is false, the algorithm won't bother considering that path, so 0 edge cycles will be ignored.

This does not mean a shortest path can't be cyclic. (if there is a negative edge cycle, you can go into an infinite loop, or if there is a zero edge cycle, a path that takes it 5 times is just as valid as one that takes it once.) It's just Dijkstra is optimized to ignore anything that takes extra pointless computing, so Dijkstra will never produce a path with a cycle. Key point here being just because a cycle is not returned, does not imply they do not exist.